# If $p,q,r$ be three positive numbers, then prove that the value of $(p+q)(q+r)(r+p) \ge 8pqr$

Tags: calculus, inequality

> If $p,q,r$ be three positive numbers, then prove that the value of $(p+q)(q+r)(r+p) \ge 8pqr$

I have tried using vieta's formula $(p+q)(q+r)(r+p) = (pq+ qr + pr)(p+q+r) - pqr$
Also tried using $(p+q+r)^2 \ge 0$ and $(p+q+r)^3 \ge 0$ , but I didn't got the answer. Please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$r (p - q)^2 + p (q - r)^2 + q (r - p)^2\geq0$$
And
$$r (p - q)^2 + p (q - r)^2 + q (r - p)^2=(p+q)(q+r)(p+r)-8pqr$$

Answer (score 6):

We have $p+q\ge 2\sqrt{pq}$ and the analogous relations. Now multiply them.

Comment: This argument is based on the [arithmetic mean geometric mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).